# File caching virtual machine problem?

Tags: virtualbox, nautilus, filesystem, ext4

I'm having this really strange issue with some VirtualBox virtual machines, and I would like the community to help me in ruling out Ubuntu as the source of the problem.

Context: VirtualBox 5.0.18 r106667 running on CentOS 7 or Ubuntu 14 hosts (makes no difference); the guest is Ubuntu 14.04.4, using a single ext4 file system. The VM also accesses a host folder using the shared folder facility (this shared folder is itself provided by an nfs server elsewhere, although that's unlikely to matter).

Symptoms: Sometimes, I update a text file (a bash script or C source code, for example) stored on the guest's file system by accessing the new version on the shared folder using Nautilus. I copy, switch to another Nautilus tab showing the local folder, and paste. Nautilus prompts for replacement authorisation. The Nautilus window shows the file timestamp and size have changed. Now I open said local file using gedit or Eclipse and...They see the older version of the file. gedit will sometime give an odd error regarding some unrecognised characters.

If I purge the file before pasting the new version, it still happens. If I reboot the VM and immediately attempt the procedure again, it still happens. I tried running 'sudo sync' on the host and guest to no avail. Running the Ubuntu installation CD image, I can fsck the VM's disk, and it checks out as being fine.

However, if I open the file in gedit from the shared folder and then do a Save As to the local folder, it gets updated correctly.

What else could I try to diagnose what is going on?

Comment: In the Nautilus menus, try selecting the `Reload` menu item after pasting the file. In 14.04.4 it's in the regular menus, but it may not be called Reload... I don't have an older system running to check for sure. In 16.10 the `Reload` choice is in one of the new button shortcuts.

Comment: @heynnema Reload (F5) should merely update the display, right? Even if the display were 'old' (which it isn't), how could this possibly affect the contents of the file?

Comment: You might try updating to Virtualbox 5.1 and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Here's another hint at what's going on. If I use cp instead of Nautilus's copy-and-paste, the file gets updated correctly. But, weirdly, it does NOT ask to overwrite although it should. I'm guessing this is a Nautilus caching problem, somehow?